# extract numbers before search string in a file

Tags: vbscript

My log looks like this

```
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - Resultate 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 1502 lines imported 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 1 header lines 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 1563 errors
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 0 changed 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 0 deleted 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 0 not changed 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 0 not found1-1 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 1 empty lines 
2013-10-22 11:29:44 +02:00 - Info - 1499 errors
```

I am new to VBScribt and in need of writing a script to get the numbers before the word **errors** in this files.

My expected output is

```
1563
1499
```

I tried searching and was not able to get a similar scenario.

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get info from short structured files is to .ReadAll() the file into memory and to apply a regular expression that cuts the desired data from the string. In code:

```
  Option Explicit
  Dim goFS     : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global = True
  reCut.Pattern = "(\d+) errors"
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\log.txt").ReadAll)
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT IN oMTS
      WScript.Echo oMT.SubMatches(0)
  Next
```

output:

```
1563
1499
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read each line backwards, detect that "error" is present then read from the following whitespace until the next whitespace.

Comment: I am completely new to VBScripts. Would it be possible to provide an example or direct me to a link having examples like these.......

Answer (score 0):

Better way to process log files is to leave the work to the correct tools. But when we dont have access to this tools, second best option is to try to read as less information into script as possible. Log files are usually really big. So, instead of reading and searching with script code, let the system do the work for you. So, `type` the file, filter with `findstr`, split records with `for` command using the spaces as delimiters and read from script only the needed data.

```
Dim oShell
    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strCommand
    strCommand = "cmd /q /c ""for /F ""tokens=7 delims= "" %f in ('type ..\data.txt ^| findstr /r ""[0-9]+ errors"" ') do echo %f """

Dim oData
    Set oData = oShell.Exec( strCommand )

Dim strData 
    strData = oData.StdOut.ReadAll()

Dim aData 
    aData = Split( strData, vbCrLf )

    WScript.Echo strData
```